# jQuery Multiple Selector Reducing Size of Collection

Tags: jquery

It was my understanding that performing a query like `jQuery(a, b)` would give you a jQuery collection containing the union of `jQuery(a)` and `jQuery(b)`. However, I encountered this situation:

```
jQuery(somediv).length ==> 1
jQuery('td').length ==> over 600
jQuery('td', somediv).length ==> 1 (the div)
```

What's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`jQuery(a, b)` means find all elements `jQuery(a)` containing in `jQuery(b)`.

it is more like `jQuery(b).find(a)`

So in your case `jQuery('td', somediv).length` returns number of `td`'s in `somediv`

Comment: A subtle distinction. :) Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I think you are confusing

```
$("td,#somediv")
```

with

$("td",somediv)

if the length of the latter is 1 it means that somediv only has 1 descendant td.

Answer (score 1):

The code below will get total number of somediv in your dom

```
  jQuery(somediv).length ==> 1
```

The code below will get total number of td in your dom

```
  jQuery('td').length ==> over 600
```

The code below will get total number of td in your somediv

```
  jQuery('td', somediv).length ==> 1 (the div)
```